# Creating a form that requires ranged numbers, the > sign and N/A, how?

Tags: php, forms, enums

I have the question "How many years have you worked in this position? With the answers being ether: 
0-5
6-10
11-15
 (greater than) 16 
N/A

I know this probably has a very simple solution, but I'm not able to parse it at the moment.

EDIT:
This has been solved, now to part 2:
THis question is a conditional. If yes is chosen the question appears, otherwise,not. I know how ot do this in php, but the html of the form is broken when the php is added, unless i did it worng, again.

Can PHP be used or do I have to use Java?

Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to create a dropdown with these options?

Comment: This is a good form design or User Interface/User Design question -- but not really a code question (yet). Based on the type of question you are asking... you would use a drop-down list, or radio buttons. Then on the backend you would choose how to store the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select` element.

```html
 <select id="question" name="yearsWorked">
  <option value="1">0-5</option>
  <option value="2">6-10</option>
  <option value="3">11-15</option>
  <option value="4">greater than 16</option>
  <option value="5">N/A</options>
</select>
```